# jquery range slider capture the values and put them in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jquery range slider and although it does display the price range by default it causes a problem with my design so I've had to hide that particular input

However I still want to show the price range which has been selected.

this is what I have but it just keeps appending things but I want them replaced (.replacewith didn't work either)

a fiddle will explain better : http://jsfiddle.net/Pyprr/98/

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//...
$("#displaypricerange").html(price3);
//...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pyprr/99/

Comment: Awe man! That was easy! Thanks for taking a look, I've a lot of learning to do!